# Add class to that specific child on hover without affecting others divs with same class

Tags: jquery, parent-child, jquery-hover

Right now I have a grid of images (setup via bootstrap). On hover, the image will grow a bit in size, and change opacity. However, that effect I just mentioned gets applied to all the icons. While I know I could remedy this by making each icon have its own ID or something, that seems unnecessary.

```
    $('.icon').hover(  
   function(){  
     /* Add 'activeIcon' class to specific img element nested in the div with the 'icon' class */
    $('.activeIcon').animate({
         width: "225px", 
         height: "225px",
         opacity: 1,
         left: "-10px",
         top: "50px"
      }, 300);  
   },
   function(){  
     $('.activeIcon').animate({
         width: "200px", 
         height: "200px",
         opacity: 0.5,
         left: "0px",
         top: "50px"
     }, 300);  
     /*Remove that class from that img */    
});
```

To give a snippit of what the html looks like -

```
       <div class="col-sm-3">
             <div class="icon">
                 <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
                 <p>title of this thing</p>
             </div>
         </div>
```

Basically a bunch of those in a row, all with the icon class. Apply the the animation to the icon class will animate all the divs. My question being how to have it isolate the one I have my mouse over.

---

Unrelated, but if anyone would have any idea why sometimes the animations triggered by the hover (essentially the mouse enter/exit) would trigger multiple times (sometimes indefinitely), I'd appreciate it. Might be my browser or something though, works fine in Fiddle.

Comment: would be helpful if you provide your html markup as well

Comment: I'm a bit confused about why you think `this` doesn't help in your situation. I think it *will* help, but I can't tell you how without seeing your html - and perhaps if you could explain more clearly which elements are supposed to change. Maybe provide a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: is `.icon` a `div`, or the `img` you're animating?

Comment: @dshun Sorry, I really should have posted it (I added it to the question). It was solved already by another user though, but thanks for your interest

Comment: @nnnnnn I guess I was too unclear. While I posted the html in the initial question now, here's what I meant by the $(this) thing. Since the hover feature was on the div with the icon class, if I had just put $(this) in there, it would affect all the other divs with the icon class, not that singular one. That's all I was saying.  User Derek posted a solution using a variable that seemed to work. Thanks for your interest in helping.

Comment: That's not how `this` works. It would just be the particular element that was hovered at the time, not all of them. Derek's solution uses `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.icon').hover(  
    function() {  
        /* Add 'activeIcon' class to specific img element nested in the div with the 'icon' class and animate it */
        var $icon = $(this);
        $icon.find('img')
            .addClass('activeIcon')
            .animate({
                width: "225px", 
                height: "225px",
                opacity: 1,
                left: "-10px",
                top: "50px"
            }, 300);
    },
    function() {  
        /* Animate the 'activeIcon' image and remove the class */
        var $icon = $(this);
        $icon.find('img.activeIcon')
            .animate({
                width: "200px", 
                height: "200px",
                opacity: 0.5,
                left: "0px",
                top: "50px"
            }, 300)
            .removeClass('activeIcon');
    }
);
```